# Inconsistent result of min function

Tags: r

This is the [datasets](https://eventing.coursera.org/api/redirectStrict/a6c-aHouOpOBuKFiI8vze3_1MisI3cPWZmC8rvGpFY2ZAQRPy4GHdzjWPk0V_YKASafYkGcyZvpY6T_I603kWw.yqf1cUk-xt69z4zn0HKgIA.Hilv42qJRUMwqt1n9kgE8EXx6dHL7qP_lgCDe9PEZrTh2NpKCCW9ng_tiLjy8sXi5kDF1aOjkJNphU_EUuzJw_k-w9cx380IEm2RD4lyGBN7ticzLJvFI82HcVsRHnmSVJSIWBvTke5j5BzEox86y4eCZtmCp_6Ss8I5nPs8CjMk80lO--9ovq1RHzSTX3UuVdOmWsMyvGXLIocV6o_TORxgXqZh4WRbWFU-RH4XWvpifY4TXWIev5sEmkvSPPv-PWHhi2IC2C4n4m6LwSeBfKeEkFK5q51WfWZePIVlSQ1OaLU8bowLU6RqFctF4KkL40zEXMuUfewvX-VSJJ9e7R04e3bk9d8Ya3sRmGIBEUIC1YfWqAcKG2kWSVBKTst-11NtfdImtKKdXGVTBf9z5KNeRlDyvWesYsRP_cJ_cEU)

```
>data<-read.csv("outcome-of-care-measures.csv", colClasses = "character") 
>state="TX"  
> data.state<-data[data$State==state,]
> min(data.state[,17])  
[1] "10.0"  
> which.min(data.state[,17])  
[1] 42  
Warning message:  
In which.min(data.state[, 17]) : NAs introduced by coercion  
> data.state[42,17]  
[1] "8.1"
```

as can be seen above `min` function yields `10.0` as minimum value while there's lower value of `8.1`, why?

Comment: It looks like your column is not numeric and `min` does not pick up on that. Change your column to numeric and you will be fine

Comment: You did this to yourself when you included `colClasses = "character"` in your call to `read.csv()`.  Why did you do that?

Comment: because without it, the imported result would contain factors level. I just removed `colClasses = "character" ` and using `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` instead and it still gives same result

Comment: This is coursera. If you look at the data for outcomes, you see that there a strings "Not available' in it. Hence the default reading in as character, and the need to convert to numeric.

Comment: What if you changed `colClasses = "character"` to `na.strings = "Not available"`.  This will make all "Not available" into NA.

Comment: Thx, i didn't noticed that the NA is in "Not Available" string before

Comment: Please make your example reproducible by avoiding linking to off-site resources. Incorporate data and code in your post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given the quotes in the result I think that column 17 is a string column. Which is causing the confusion.

the correct result can be calculated by `min(as.numeric(data.state[,17]))`

Comment: maybe `min(as.numeric(data.state[,17]))` instead?

Comment: Pretty obvious that it's character since that's what he asked for in `read.csv()` ;-)